# I have an error opening trace file and a unable to start activity compotentInfo and no fix seems to work, Android

Tags: android, runtime

Error(s):
10-17 18:53:39.298: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quizme/com.quizme.QuizMeActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-17 18:53:38.747: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Upon trying to run it I get the unfortunatly, the app does not work error as well.
Java file:

```
package com.quizme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizMeActivity extends Activity  {

private TextView question;
private TextView result;
private ImageButton forward;
private ImageButton backward;
private Button bTrue;
private Button bFalse;
private TrueFalse mTrueFalse;


    /*
     * onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     * Instantiates all private GUI elements to their corresponding Views
     * in activity_quiz_me.xml
     * Sets the string values of the questions in the TrueFalse object,
     * and sets their truth values.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_me);

        Resources res = this.getResources(); //this is to be able to get strings
        bTrue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        forward=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.forward_button);
        bFalse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        backward=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        result.setText("");
        question=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        question.setText(mTrueFalse.getmQuestionSet()[0]);








        mTrueFalse.setmQuestionSet(0, (String) res.getText(R.string.q1));
        mTrueFalse.setmQuestionSet(1, (String) res.getText(R.string.q2));
        mTrueFalse.setmQuestionSet(2, (String) res.getText(R.string.q3));
        mTrueFalse.setmQuestionSet(3, (String) res.getText(R.string.q4));
        mTrueFalse.setmQuestionSet(4, (String) res.getText(R.string.q5));

        mTrueFalse.setmArrOfBols(0, false);
        mTrueFalse.setmArrOfBols(1, true);
        mTrueFalse.setmArrOfBols(2, true);
        mTrueFalse.setmArrOfBols(3, false);
        mTrueFalse.setmArrOfBols(4, true);


    }


     public void checkTrue(View view) {
         Resources res = this.getResources(); //this is to be able to get strings

         if(mTrueFalse.getCurrentBolValue()==true)
         {
             result.setText((String) res.getText(R.string.right));
         }
         else 
         {
             result.setText((String) res.getText(R.string.wrong));
         }

     }
     public void checkFalse(View view) {
         Resources res = this.getResources(); //this is to be able to get strings

         if(mTrueFalse.getCurrentBolValue()==true)
         {
             result.setText((String) res.getText(R.string.wrong));
         }
         else 
         {
             result.setText((String) res.getText(R.string.right));
         }

     }
     public void goForward(View view) {
         if(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()<mTrueFalse.getmQuestionSet().length-1)
         {
             mTrueFalse.setmCurrentQ(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()+1);
             question.setText((String) (mTrueFalse.getCurrentQuestionStr()));
             result.setText("");

         }
         else if(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()==mTrueFalse.getmQuestionSet().length-1)
         {
             mTrueFalse.setmCurrentQ(0);
             question.setText((String) (mTrueFalse.getCurrentQuestionStr()));
             result.setText("");

         }

     }

     public void goBack(View view) {
        if(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()>0)
        {
             mTrueFalse.setmCurrentQ(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()-1);
             question.setText((String) (mTrueFalse.getCurrentQuestionStr()));
             result.setText("");

        }
        else if(mTrueFalse.getmCurrentQ()==0)
         {

             mTrueFalse.setmCurrentQ(mTrueFalse.getmQuestionSet().length-1); //for the purposes of the project, its setting currentQ to 4
             question.setText((String) (mTrueFalse.getCurrentQuestionStr()));
             result.setText("");

         }
     }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz_me, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

}
```

layout xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_view"
    tools:context="com.quizme.QuizMeActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sTrue"
        android:layout_marginRight="180dp"
        android:onClick="checkTrue"
    />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/forward_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/back_button"
        android:onClick="goForward"
        android:src="@drawable/forward" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/question"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/true_button"
        android:onClick="checkFalse"
        android:text="@string/sFalse" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back"
        android:onClick="goBack"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/resultStr"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/forward_button"
        android:text="@string/questionStr"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest:

```
     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".QuizMeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

sorry for the pile of code, I am just frustrated and stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project

Eclipse: **Project->Clean**